# Matching Input & Output Hardware Settings for AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio

I am trying to build a very simple audio effects chain using Core Audio for iOS. So far I have implemented an EQ - Compression - Limiter chain which works perfectly fine in the simulator. However on device, the application crashes when connecting nodes to the **AVAudioEngine** due to an apparent mismatch in the input and output hardware formats.

```
'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false:
 IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(outputHWFormat)'
```

Taking a basic example, my Audio Graph is as follows.

```
Mic -> Limiter -> Main Mixer (and Output)
```

and the graph is populated using

```
engine.connect(engine.inputNode!, to: limiter, format: engine.inputNode!.outputFormatForBus(0))
engine.connect(limiter, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: engine.inputNode!.outputFormatForBus(0))
```

which crashes with the above exception. If I instead use the limiter's format when connecting to the mixer

```
engine.connect(engine.inputNode!, to: limiter, format: engine.inputNode!.outputFormatForBus(0))
engine.connect(limiter, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: limiter.outputFormatForBus(0))
```

the application crashes with an *kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported* error

```
'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -10868'
```

Before connecting the audio nodes in the engine, inputNode has 1 channel and a sample rate of 44.100Hz, while the outputNode has 0 channels and a sample rate of 0Hz (deduced using *outputFormatForBus(0)* property). But this could be because there is no node yet connected to the output mixer? Setting the *preferred sample rate* on **AVAudioSession** made no difference.

Is there something that I am missing here? I have Microphone access (verified using *AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission()*), and I have set the **AVAudioSession** mode to record (*AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)*).

The limiter is an **AVAudioUnitEffect** initialized as follows:

```
let limiter = AVAudioUnitEffect( audioComponentDescription:
                AudioComponentDescription(
                    componentType: kAudioUnitType_Effect,
                    componentSubType: kAudioUnitSubType_PeakLimiter,
                    componentManufacturer: kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple,
                    componentFlags: 0,
                    componentFlagsMask: 0) )
engine.attachNode(limiter)
```

and engine is a global, class variable

```
var engine = AVAudioEngine()
```

As I said, this works perfectly fine using the simulator (and Mac's default hardware), but continually crashes on various iPads on iOS8 & iOS9. I have a super basic example working which simply feeds the mic input to a player to the output mixer

```
do {
     file = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: NSURL.URLToDocumentsFolderForName(name: "test", WithType type: "caf")!, settings: engine.inputNode!.outputFormatForBus(0).settings)
} catch {}
engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: file.processingFormat)
```

Here the inputNode has 1 channel and 44.100Hz sampling rate, while the outputNode has 2 channels and 44.100Hz sampling rate, but no mismatching seems to occur. Thus the issue must be the manner in which the AVAudioUnitEffect is connected to the output mixer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: AVAUdio is a terrible pain in the rear, documentation is poorly written, and the engine works according really obscure rules, and unhelpful error codes. It sucks, but we have to plow forward. I will post an answer if I solve it.

Comment: do you have a project that reproduces this?

Answer (score 14):

This depends on some factors outside of the code you've shared, but it's possible you're using the wrong AVAudioSession category.

I ran into this same issue, under some slightly different circumstances. When I was using AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord as the AVAudioSession category, I ran into this same issue when attempting to connect an audio tap.  I not only received that error, but my AVAudioEngine inputNode showed an outputFormat with 0.0 sample rate.

Changing it to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord I received the expected 44.100Hz sample rate and the issue resolved.